# Simple Text Field Calculations Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

I have gotten pretty far with this, it seems like a simple calculation, but for some reason my code isn't producing the results I need.

I'm trying to create a calculator that does the following.  The user inputs their weight and body fat percentage.  They also input their recommended daily water ratio and daily protein ratio.

Next the calculator will take the entered weight and body fat percentage and multiply it to get the lbs of weight that are fat, then it will take the weight and subtract the lbs of weight that are fat to come up with the lean body mass.

Next it will take the lean body mass and multiply it by the recommended daily water ratio to calculate the daily water intake.

Finally it will take the lean body mass and multiply it by the recommended daily protein ratio to calculate the daily protein intake.

Here is what I have thus far.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


<head>
<title>Dr. Kosimides Lean Body Academy Calculator</title>


<style type = "text/css">
    body
    {
        background:#FFC;
    }

    div
    {
        border:2px solid #F69;
        padding:10px 40px;
        background:#FCC;
        width:600px;
        border-radius:20px;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 2px #CCC;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
    }

    h1
    {
        color:#F06
        text-align:center;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
        <form>
            <h1>LBA Calculator</h1>
            <br />
            <label> Weight
                    <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" /> (lbs)
            </label>
            <label> Body Fat
                    <input type="text" name="bodyfat" id="bodyfat" /> (%)
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
             <label> Protein
                    <input type="text" name="protein" id="protein" />
            </label>
            <br />
             <label> Water
                    <input type="text" name="water" id="water" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
             <label> Pounds of Body Fat
                    <input type="text" name="lbf" id="lbf" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Lean Body Mass
                    <input type="text" name="lbm" id="lbm" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Daily Water Intake
                    <input type="text" name="dwi" id="dwi" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <label> Daily Protein Intake
                    <input type="text" name="dpi" id="dpi" />
            </label>
            <input type="button" name="Calculate" value="Calculate" onClick="LBAcalc()" />
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="reset" />
        </form>
        </div>

        <script>

            function LBAcalc()
            {


                     // Get The Input

                    var w_txt = document.getElementById('weight');
                    var bf_txt = document.getElementById('bodyfat');
                    var p_txt = document.getElementById('protein');
                    var h20_txt = document.getElementById('water');


                     // Convert To Numbers If Needed

                    var w = parseInt(w_txt.value);
                    var bf = parseInt(bf_txt.value);
                    var p = parseInt(p_txt.value);
                    var h20 = parseInt(h20_txt.value);


                    // Convert body fat to percentage

                    bf = bf / 100;


                    // Validate Inputs

                    var errMsg = "";

                    if (w <= 0)
                      errMsg = errMsg + "*Weight cannot be negative \n";

                    if (w == "")
                      errMsg = errMsg + "*Weight must be entered \n";

                    if ( bf <= 0)
                      errMsg = errMsg + "*Body Fat cannot be negative \n";     


                    // If Error Inform User

                    if (errMsg != "")

                        alert(errMsg);

                    else


                    // If No Error Process and Display Results

                    var result = document.getElementById ('lbf');
                    var myResult = w * bf;
                    result.value = myResult.toFixed(1);

                    var result1 = document.getElementById ('lbm');
                    var myResult1 = w - myResult;
                    result1.value = myResult1.toFixed(1);

                    var result2 = document.getElementById ('dwi');
                    var myResult2 = w * myResult1;
                    result2.value = myResult2.toFixed(1);

                    var result3 = document.getElementById ('dpi');
                    var myResult3 = myResult * p;
                    result3.value = myResult3.toFixed(1);


            }



        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code looks perfect for me. What exactly are you expecting but what's it producing?

Comment: Hey, you forgot a `{` after `else`.

Comment: your `else` after `if (errMsg != "")` doesn't have a `{}`

Answer (score 0):

What you have got till now is alright. Only the problem is, you forgot to enclose multiple items inside `else`:

```
else {
  // If No Error Process and Display Results

  var result = document.getElementById ('lbf');
  var myResult = w * bf;
  result.value = myResult.toFixed(1);

  var result1 = document.getElementById ('lbm');
  var myResult1 = w - myResult;
  result1.value = myResult1.toFixed(1);

  var result2 = document.getElementById ('dwi');
  var myResult2 = w * myResult1;
  result2.value = myResult2.toFixed(1);

  var result3 = document.getElementById ('dpi');
  var myResult3 = myResult * p;
  result3.value = myResult3.toFixed(1);
}
```

It is perfectly okay, if you aren't having more than one statement. Like how you have it in the previous `if` statements. But when there are more than one, you **need** to use `{ }` to enclose them. If not, it will execute only the first statement, for the `else` condition and executes all the statements after first, irrespective of the condition.